# How to I fix this VBA code for special sort so that I do not get object errors?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a special sort to sort multiple columns in a spreadsheet, in this case- 3. However, the SetRange and the code below it seems to be gettings an error of "Object doesn't support this property or method."

if I take away the With statement I have a different error of "Invalid or unqualified sequence."

the line that is highlighted is .SetRange Range("A1:I35") and the error is 438 Object doesnt support this property or method

How do I proceed in fixing this error?

```
Sub Sort()
With ActiveSheet
' Sort Macro

Cells.Select

    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A2:A35" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B2:B35" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("H2:H35" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range("A1:I35")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted and what is the exact error (number and description)? Is the code in the workbook containing this worksheet? Will you be applying this to more than one worksheet? If not, what is the tab name of the worksheet? You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72173758/edit) at any time.

Comment: @VBasic2008 the line that is highlighted is .SetRange Range("A1:I35") and the error is 438 Object doesnt support this property or method

Comment: I will be applying it to more than one worksheet

Answer (score 2):

### Sort a Range

```vb
Sub SortData()

    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    'Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Sort _
            Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Key2:=.Columns(2), Order2:=xlAscending, _
            Key3:=.Columns(8), Order3:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't quite using the `With` statement correctly.  Try it like this:

```
Sub Sort()
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
    
        Cells.Select
    
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 key:=Range("A2:A35" _
            ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add2 key:=Range("B2:B35" _
            ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add2 key:=Range("H2:H35" _
            ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range("A1:I35")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```